# SyntaxError traces back to File "<string>" line 19

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I run my code it gives me a SyntaxError that I don't understand and always points back to the second line of this code:

```
gen_item = '''
def__getitem__(self,index):
    if type(index) == str:
        if index not in self._fields:
            raise IndexError("Index matches no fields.")
        else:
            return self.index
    elif type(index) == int:
        if index > len(self._fields) - 1:
            raise IndexError("Index out of range.")
        else:
            return self._fields[index]\n'''
```

with the message "File "< string>" line 19". I'm not sure what the problem is seeing as this is all one big triple-quoted string. I'm using Python 3.3.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python3.3.2

Comment: If I add a  # (as if it's a comment) to the beginning of the line in question, it makes the error go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SyntaxError` is being raised by wherever you are `exec`ing that string.  Thusly:

```
In [209]: s = '''
     ...: blah blah blah syntax error
     ...: 
     ...: blah blah'''

In [210]: exec(s)
  File "<string>", line 2
    blah blah blah syntax error
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Your actual syntax error is this:

```
def__getitem__(self,index):
```

You're missing a space in between `def` and `__getitem__`.